# How to fix MongoDB in jupyter?

Tags: mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

````
```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client['VentiLife']
    collection = db['Hospitals']
    
    # User's coordinates
    user_latitude, user_longitude = 22.2765399829831, 73.19971991285121   
    
    print(user_latitude, user_longitude)
    
    
    def find_nearest_hospital(latitude, longitude):
        # Create a 2D index on the "location" field
        collection.create_index([("location", "2dsphere")])
    
        # Find the nearest hospital using the $near and $maxDistance operators
        nearest_hospital = collection.find_one({
            "location": {
                "$near": {
                    "$geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
                    },
                     "$maxDistance": 1000 
                }
            }
        })
    
        return nearest_hospital
    
    nearest_hospital = find_nearest_hospital(user_latitude, user_longitude)
    if nearest_hospital:
        print(f"Nearest Hospital: {nearest_hospital['name']}")
        latitude, longitude = nearest_hospital["location"]["coordinates"] 
    else:
        print("No hospitals found.")
```
````

when i write following query in MongoDB compass it works perfectly but when i run above script in jupyter , it gives me no hospital found. so i have to comment out $maxDistance to get result but it is not the nearest one present in my database.

```
{
    "location": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
            },
             "$maxDistance": 1000 
        }
```

Comment: Why are you creating the index in the `find_nearest_hospital` call?   The index should be created "outside" of the query logic and done only once.    Also: try adding a `print` or 2 and maybe a `find_one` to ensure your script is actually hitting the DB and can fetch anything at all.